# What goes in the ' [ ] ' in ' apt[ ] ' in bash?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

i'm learning to touch type and I pressed ' [ ' instead of ' - ' . When I went on to the next line I couldn't do anything until i typed in k].

I then got a command not found error.
is this a 'apt-get' thing or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Unrelated, afaik you should be able to use `apt install`, ... instead of `apt-get install`...

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the bash syntax for setting array elements.

If `arr` is an array variable,

```
arr[7]=Seventh
```

sets element 7 of the array to the string Seventh. So if bash is expecting a possible assignment, then it interprets `word[` as a subscript operator, even if `word` is not a known array variable. (It will be created as an array variable if it is not already an array variable.)

Array subscripts are numeric contexts (unless the array has been declared as an associative array). In a numeric context, you can type an arithmetic expression without using `$` as a variable sigil. In numeric contexts, whitespace is ignored, so the newline is ok.

Had `apt` been declared as an associative array, you could still assign an element using, for example,

```
apt[
key
]=42
```

However, in this case, the newlines are not ignored, so they become part of the key.

If there is no `=` following the `]`, then the word was not an array assignment, so it is treated as a word. But by then it has already been read, newlines and all. (Pathname expansion occurs after word-splitting, so `bash` will try to match the word with a filename in the current directory, using the characters, including the newline, between the `[` and `]` as a character class.)

Comment: "*If there is no = following the ], then the word was not an array assignment, so it is treated literally as a word.*" - only if there are no matching filenames

Comment: @cdarke: That's true; filename expansion happens after word-splitting. I suppose the word "literally" was badly-chosen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an `apt-get` thing, this is a shell thing.

As @rici says, if you were doing an assignment, then the `[ ]` notation would be used for array element modification.  But you are not, so it isn't.

This is part of *globbing*, also known as wildcards, or filename expansion.  The `[ ]` bracket notation is known as a *character class*, and is a range or list of alternative characters, matching one character in the filename.  For example, `[123]` means "1" or "2" or "3", and could also be written as `[1-3]`.

The thing about globbing is that (in bash) a failure to find a file which matches the pattern means that the literal is passed as a command.  Assuming you did not have a file called `apt[\n]` in your current directory, it would try to execute a program by that name!  (`\n` is a common notation for a new-line character).

Here is an example test script:

```
# Let's create some files
touch apt1 apt2 apt3

# Let's see the expansion
set -x

apt[
]

apt[
123
]
```

Here are the results, the `+` is the prompt (`PS4`) given by the xtrace (set -x):

```
+ 'apt[
]'
gash.sh: line 10: $'apt[\n]': command not found
```

So with the first one it was looking for a file with that pattern.

```
+ apt1 apt2 apt3
gash.sh: line 14: apt1: command not found
```

But with the second one the `\n` is treated as whitespace and it matches the filenames.  `apt1` is not a script in `$PATH` so it does not find it as a command.
You will notice that it has expanded to all the filenames that match, not just one.

Comment: However, except in this very peculiar situation, if you wanted to put a newline inside a character class for pathname substitution, you'd need to quote it.